# Regex from ruby string to bash

Tags: ruby, regex, shell

I am trying the pass the `sed -i '' 's/,\([^ '\''"]\)/, \1/g' app/models/campaign.rb` command from my ruby program, but i am not able to get the string right (esp for the double quote and the backslash part). Does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Comment: I'm curious *why* you're trying to do this.

Comment: Do yourself this favor:  Get it working in bash*, then move it to Ruby.  You'll have to double every backslash, then re-escape whatever quotation marks you used to delineate the string.  (*Or whatever shell you're using.)